# PostgreSQL - Expiry date value AFTER password is changed

Tags: postgresql, passwords

Our company has a policy of changing passwords on a pretty regular schedule, and this is easily done with UNIX O/S commands. They have routines that require strict requirements for length, minimum digits, etc. And also have an expiry date that reminds you to change the password and sets a new expiry date when you change it.

We are using **PostgreSQL 10** databases and want to set up expiry dates for the ODBC user accounts in there too. I know there is the `ALTER USER {username} VALID UNTIL {date}` option. One concern I have is what happens to the expiry date we have set if the user (or anyone) issues the `\password` command. I can't seem to find that mentioned anywhere.

Example: On March 4, I set up user "odbcuser" and set the password to be valid until July 4. On July 1, the user issues `\password odbcuser` and sets a new password. Is the `VALID UNTIL` still set to July 4, or does that value get reset to NULL or infinity? Or is it still going to expire in three days, after the password was just changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough to test:

```
create role pwd_valid with password '1234' valid until '08/09/2020';

rolname      rolvaliduntil
-------      -------------
pwd_valid    08/09/2020 00:00:00 PDT

alter role pwd_valid with password 'testpass';

rolname      rolvaliduntil
-------      -------------
pwd_valid    08/09/2020 00:00:00 PDT
```

So the expiration date stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adrian,

Funny you mention that. After posting my question, I did exactly that test and confirmed that the PostgreSQL 10 that I was using did NOT change the valuntil column. But I figured I'd leave the question up in case someone had some additional insight as to the subject. Like maybe there is a change coming in PG12 or other that I did not find.

I guess there is also no setting in one of the pg_ system tables to say when was the last time the password was changed?

Because even setting the valid until, I won't know if someone changed their password. I'd have to make a password procedure that changes the password and resets the valid until date to NOW + 180 days.

Comment: The example I showed was run in Postgres 12, so no changes.  The system tables will not show when the password was changed.